# Realtime Searchbox returns old search results

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a Realtime Searchbox on my website but when I type another product that isnt relatable it sometimes returns the old results in the top of the list, so I was wondering if there is something not right in my code or if some additional code can fix this. If something doesnt seem right, ask me. Ill be happy to reply. full codeshare: https://codeshare.io/5eKyvL

```
var delay = (function () {
        var timer = 0;
        return function (callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();
var initSearchEvents = function () {
        getElement().keyup(function (e) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var data = {
                    title : value
                };
                if (value.length >= getMinchars()) {
                    searchRedirect(data);
                }
                return false;
            }
            delay(function () {
                if (value.length >= getMinchars()) {
                    ajaxRequest(value);
                } else {
                    hideResults();
                }
            }, 300);
        });
        getElement().click(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value.length >= getMinchars())
                ajaxRequest(value);
            else
                hideResults();
        });
        getShowAllResultsElement().click(function () {
            var data = {
                "title" : getElement().val()
            };
            searchRedirect(data);
        });
}
var ajaxSuccessPagination = function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            if (data.total > 0) {
                setTotalItems(data.total);
                showResults(data.rows);
                (data.suggestions != undefined && data.suggestions.length > 
                0) ? showSuggestions(data.suggestions) : closeSuggestions();
            } else {
                noResults();
            }
        } else {
            error("Ajax call returned false");
            noResults();
        }
    };
```

showResults:

```
    var ajaxSuccess = function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            if (data.total > 0) {
                setTotalItems(data.total);
                setPaginationValues();
                showResults(data.rows);
                setExitPopupEvents();
                (data.suggestions != undefined && data.suggestions.length > 0) ? showSuggestions(data.suggestions) : closeSuggestions();
            } else {
                noResults();
            }
        } else {
            noResults();
        }
    }
    var ajaxSuccessPagination = function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            if (data.total > 0) {
                setTotalItems(data.total);
                showResults(data.rows);
                (data.suggestions != undefined && data.suggestions.length > 0) ? showSuggestions(data.suggestions) : closeSuggestions();
            } else {
                noResults();
            }
        } else {
            error("Ajax call returned false");
            noResults();
        }
    };
    var ajaxError = function (data) {
        error("Ajax call failed");
    };
    var showResults = function (data) {
        var jResults = getResultsElement();
        $.when(getResultsElements().remove()).then(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < getLimit() && i < data.length; i++) {
                var jResult = $('<li>');
                jResult.append('<div class="left">' + '<a href="' + data[i].url + '">' + '<img alt="' + data[i].description + '" title="' + data[i].description + '" src="' + data[i].image_src + '" />' + '</a>' + '</div>' + '<div class="right">' + '<h4>' + '<a href="' + data[i].url + '">' +
                    data[i].title + '</a>' + '</h4>' + '<h5>' + '<span>vanaf</span>' + ' ' + data[i].price + '</h5>' + '</div>' + '<div class="more">' + '<a href="' + data[i].url + '">More</a>' + '</div>');
                jResults.append(jResult);
            }
            var pageCount = getTotalItems() / getLimit();
            getResultsElementWrapper().show();
        });
```

Comment: where is the showResults function?

Comment: Sorry, I've added them!

Comment: where is the getResultsElement function?

Comment: here is a full codeshare: https://codeshare.io/5eKyvL